# Jackson + KotlinModule: Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'isFoo')

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-modules

Stumbling through a strange behaviour in `Jackson` when used with `KotlinModule`. Trying to deserialize a JSON object with `isXxx`-Boolean and `xxx`-none-Boolean property. Any solution how to deal with this?

```
    data class FooObject(
        @JsonProperty("isFoo")
        val isFoo: Boolean,
        @JsonProperty("foo")
        val foo: String,
    )

    @Test
    fun `deserialization should work` (){
        val serialized = """
            {
              "isFoo": true,
              "foo": "bar"
            }
        """.trimIndent()

        val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
            .modules(KotlinModule())
            .build()

        val deserialized = objectMapper.readValue(serialized, FooObject::class.java)

        assertNotNull(deserialized)
    }

throws
```

Results in

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'isFoo'): found multiple explicit names: [isFoo, foo], but also implicit accessor: [method org.dnltsk.Test$FooObject#getFoo()][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false], [method org.dnltsk.Test$FooObject#isFoo()][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false]
```

By removing the `@JsonProperty`-annotations the exception turns to

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Duplicate creator property "isFoo" (index 0 vs 1) for type `org.dnltsk.Test$FooObject` 
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "isFoo": true,
  "foo": "bar"
}"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Comment: Current workaround is a substitution of `@JsonProperty("foo") val foo: String` with `@JsonProperty("foo") val theFoo: String` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following annotation to the top of your data class:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(
    getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
    isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
)
```